# Dynamic variable names from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python

I'm coming from Matlab and need to reimplement some data processing in python/numpy. I have data files which are in a specific format, but it can vary which variables are listed in the file.

In matlab I could write functions to stick the data arrays in handy structs, like this:

```
s = data_to_struct(filename)
s.altitude
s.time
s.latitude
s.longitude
s.density
s.temperature
```

which I could then pass around to various plotting or filtering functions. I want to do the same in Python, using an object in place of the struct. I know the Proper™ way is to use a dict, but for this very specific and limited case the dict syntax is uglier in my eyes:  **s.temperature** vs **s['temperature']**, as well as being more cumersome to type. What is the best way to read a string of variable names from file, and then create variables or object members with those names?

I will do a lot of interactive plotting and data handling, and I want to make the typing and tabbing as easy as possible.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'll go with setattr() for now, and make a note of NamedTuple and Pandas for future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `obj.attr = value` you can also write `setattr(obj, 'attr', value)` which takes the attribute name as a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Something = namedtuple('Something', 'a b c')
>>> a = Something(1, 2, 4)
>>> a.c
4
```

[namedtuple documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

this comes especially handy, if you've already deserialized your data and it exists as a collection of multiple tuples of the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It has [fast and flexible functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html) for reading data from various file formats, such as [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html), and DataFrame columns can be referenced by attribute lookup:

```
In [168]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

In [169]: df
Out[169]: 
   foo  bar  baz
0    0    1    2
1    3    4    5
2    6    7    8
3    9   10   11

[4 rows x 3 columns]

In [170]: df.bar
Out[170]: 
0     1
1     4
2     7
3    10
Name: bar, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

The one problem I see with `namedtuple` is that you can't edit the values of the object after it's been instantiated, which I don't know if you need to do or not.

While it might be a bit convoluted, you could create an object using `setattr` and basically create a factory that will generate objects with your custom attributes.

An example would look like this:

```
def data_to_struct(*info):
    class O(object):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            for a in args:
                setattr(self, a, None)
    return O(*info)
```

Then, using it, you'd pass `data_to_struct` a list of strings that will be your attribute names and get back an object that has all of those as empty attributes.

```
>>> g = data_to_struct('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> g.a
>>> g.b = 3
>>> g.b
3
```

You could of course always choose to use `kwargs` also or something else to provide values to the various attributes upon instantiation.